# Persitent mkusb Ubuntu Live USB Completely Unusable

Tags: live-usb, 23.10, mkusb

Environment: ubuntu 23.10.1 iso, USB 31GB Leef Bridge-C, booted persistent ubuntu from grub boot menue, macpro 2013, AMDGPU, 32GB RAM.

Steps to repeat:

1. download ubuntu iso and create persistent ubuntu using mkusb successfully
2. boot from usb into persistent ubuntu (on MacPro you hold the Alt button until USB drive shows after keyboard LEDs first light up)
3. boot extremely slow 1hr
4. completely unusable after boot

Any button on the UI selected including the initial language selection takes 10min or so to complete. Many errors are detected by Ubuntu and it asks to create and send error reports, which i did. Any application selected such as disks never loads, snap store loads after 30min, but selecting update only generates errors, it appears the USB isn't writeable or persistent at all.

Work around select ubuntu live from grub boot menue. Boots quickly, fully functioning ubuntu with acceptable delays and app load times.

Comment: At first I should mention, that mkusb is developed for PC computers and laptops typically delivered with Windows, but not developed for Mac computers. So I am not surprised, that there are problems with a Mac computer. (There are also success stories about mkusb and Mac, but I think very few people have used persistent live systems by mkusb on Mac computers.) -- Which of the mkusb methods did you use to create a persistent live system: 1. dus-iso2usb, 2. dus-persistent or 3. mkusb-plug?

Comment: Can you specify the error reports that you sent (for example by internet links or bug numbers (plus bug forum)? Or were they simply sent autoamatically to Ubuntu without telling you any bug numbers? Anyway, if you are interested and have the time to test a few things, please let me know, and I can suggest a few (new) things to try, that might help you find a way to run Ubuntu (or maybe a light-weight Ubuntu flavour for example Lubuntu or Xubuntu) persistent live.